# Script to get appropriate rpm package

Tags: centos, rpm

I've two packages available on CentOS 7 system:

1. `package-6.34-1.el7.i686.rpm (32-bit)`
2. `package-6.34-1.el7.x86_64.rpm (64-bit)`

I'm looking for a command to fetch the appropriate package full name based on the OS version/architecture (32/64bit).

E.g., when I query from a 64bit OS I should get the latest rpm with full name `package-6.34-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`, as I need to install package with `rpm` command:

`rpm -i --replacefiles <packagename>.rpm`

Answer (score 4):

```
rpm -i package-6.34-1.el7.$(uname -m).rpm
```

or

```
yum install package-6.34-1.el7.$(uname -m).rpm
```

Though `yum` should automatically infer the release (`el7`) and architecture if you provide it `yum install package` and you're looking for the latest version in your configured repositories.

Comment: You should also have the yum line as well `yum install package-6.34-1.el7.$(uname -m).rpm`